# Operações matemáticas de valores textbox que vem com sifrão ex: R$2,00

Tags: c#

Bom dia GALERA, estou um problema para fazer esse código em C#

Tenho um valor em um textbox que vem automático com o "R$" ai eu estou precisando pegar o valor que vem nesse textbox e fazer operações matemáticas com eles. Alguém poderia me ajudar com a conversão para fazer as operações, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eae Neto, primeiro você terá que trabalhar com essa string (Texto que você pega do TextInput), você terá de usar o método substring para tirar esse cifrão, o método substring "cortará" sua string em um pedaço menor.
Exemplo:

```
TextoTrabalhado = TextoQueVocePuxouDoTextInput.Substring(PosiçãoDoInícioDoCorte,PosiçãoDoFinalDoCorte);
```

Depois terá de converter esse texto já trabalhado em um valor numérico, com o método Parse.
Exemplo:

```
ValorNumérico = Int32.Parse(TextoTrabalhado);
```

Comment: Value brother, deu certo. Muito obrigado !.

Comment: Coloca minha resposta como correta aí, ajuda na reputação :)

Comment: Brother, tenho outra dúvida. Como resultado eu tenho um valor EX: R$3520,85 , teria como colocar os pontos corretos tipo EX:R$3.520,85 ?

Comment: Tem sim, você tem que fazer o seguinte, tem que pegar o número de caracteres do Text que você pegou do input, e fazer um algoritmo a partir daí, por exemplo, se tiver 6 caracteres (9876,54) você tem que pegar colocar o ponto depois da posição 0 (que nesse caso é a 9)